# How do you find the line number of a string in a byte array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, go, file-io, binaryfiles

**What I'm trying to find:**

- A function definition within a code file.

**Information I have:**

- Code file.
- The byte index of where the function definition starts in the code file and length in bytes.

**How should I go about finding this function's line number in the file?**

**My current thoughts:**

- Read code file as byte array
- Find function inside byte array by using start index and length for end.
- Convert this function from binary to text.
- Convert whole code file from binary to text.
- Number the lines in the text.
- Pattern match to find where the function is in the text and return line number.

I'm using Golang for the back-end service which I believe will execute this functionality. Though I also have a front-end in JavaScript which I can leverage to help if needed.

Comment: What have you tried? What issues did you run into? Can you show your code?

Comment: Assuming that you have the contents of the file`p` as type `[]byte` and the byte index of the function as int `i`, then `bytes.Count(p[:i], []byte{'\n'}) + 1` returns the line number for the function.

Comment: @BaytaDarell This worked! I also tried doing this concept with a basic for loop iteration and counting newlines. However your one liner solution is faster, would you know why that is? If you could post your solution as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you have the contents of the file `p` as type `[]byte` and the byte index of the function as int `i`, then `bytes.Count(p[:i], []byte{'\n'}) + 1` returns the line number for the function.

Answer (score 0):

Would something like counting newline characters be good enough, or are you looking into something more tweaky?

You could just start counting newlines `\n` until you reach the byte index.
The line number is the number of newline characters.

Comment: That makes sense, though I was under the impression that the byte array would be of the format [102, 97, 65 etc...], basically ASCII format. Since ASCII of newline is '10', you are suggesting to iterate to find the number of '10's until I reach the start byte index correct?